# How can I find only the Greatest Prime Factor of three integers in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I have my MIPS algorithm to print the Greatest Common Factor of three integers. For example in this code, if you enter 12, 18 and 24, you get the output 6 which is the Greatest Common Factor. But I want the code to print 3 as it is the Greatest Common Prime Factor in all of these integers. How can I do this by amending the code I have? Can anyone help me please? I am new to MIPS and I have been working on this code for the past week. Here is my code:

```
main:
.data

    prompt: .asciiz "Enter 3 positive numbers: "
    message1: .asciiz "\n First integer: "
    message2: .asciiz "\n Second integer: "
    message3: .asciiz "\n Third integer: "
    message4: .asciiz "\n The Greatest Common Prime Factor is:"

cd:
.text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message1
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message2
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message3
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t2, $v0

    #move $t0, $k0
    #move $t1, $k1
    #move $t2, $k2

loop:
    beq $t1, $0, done
    div $t0, $t1
    move $t0, $t1
    mfhi $t1
    j loop

done:   
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message4
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0   
    #move $v0, $t0
    #jr $ra
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Is the GCPF always the largest prime factor of the GCF?  (I think probably).  If so, just factor the GCF after doing this, e.g. with a naive trial-division loop, or better factoring out small prime factors as you find them, so your loop will end sooner (when quotient <= divisor you've gone past sqrt(number))

Comment: This code does not find the GCF of three numbers.  You can see that it never does anything with the last/third user entry except move it from `$v0` to `$t2`, and these otherwise go unused.  So by simple reading of the code it cannot possibly be taking the third entry into account.

Comment: Suggest to work out an algorithm you want in C first, and test it to make sure it works.  Then take that to assembly, faithfully.  The only bugs you'll have in assembly are then simple assembly typos, instead of algorithmic issues.  Some say, well I don't need it in C, but this divide & conquer approach (algorithm in C, then translate working algorithm to assembly) makes assembly programming much simpler.

Comment: (Also, stay away from the `$k` registers, and fwiw, there's no `$k2` anyway.)